# EF Code first, Insert record to auto generated table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Create Two class in Models folder Like this:

Material.cs:

```
public class Material
{
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Project { get; set; }
}
```

Project.cs:

```
 public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Material> Material { get; set; }

}
```

Entity framework code first generate a new table with name `MaterialProjects` in my SQL server database. I use scaffolding to generate `Controllers` and `Views`.

`MaterialProjects` have two Columns like this:

1. `Material_MaterialId`
2. `Project_ProjectId`

In 1st step I add a new project record into `Projects` table.
In 2nd step I add a new material record into `Materials` table.

My question is: How can I add a record to `MaterialProjects` table. I cant access   this entity in my code.

UPDATE:
Have I do this in Materials controller create Action method?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "MaterialId,Name,")] Material material)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Materials.Add(material);
            //what to do here
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(material);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to add in that table it will be done by EF automaticaly . The only thing you need to do id to add your entities correctly  and the junction table will be filled by EF you dont have to do that .

```
In controller  you can do like this  .I tested with console application.

            [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "MaterialId,Name,")] Material material)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

         using (var ctx = new SampleDbContext())
        {
            -- here context is the DBCOntext class of your application 
            --var mat = new Material
            --{
            --    Name = "A",
            --    Project = new List<Project> {new Project {Name = "P1", Date = DateTime.Now}}
            --};

            ctx.Materials.Add(material);           
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(material);
    }
```

Comment: @distance please check my answer .

Comment: @distance : You can omit the project if you dont have to add it . I just created a sample code to test if you add project it will be inserted as well .

Answer (score 0):

EF automatically handles the Many-Many junction tables.In your case, say you want to insert a new `Project` with two new `Material` entities. You can do this by assigning the materials collection to the `Material` collection of the new `Project` entity. EF will inset a new Project and two new materials and will automatically populate the junction table as well

*Updating after OP updates the question*
Hoping that you have already have the Project entity inserted (say, the id of that project is 100). So while adding new Material entity:

```
var proj = context.Projects.Find (100);
newMaterialObject.Projects.Add (proj);
context.SaveChanges();
```